# having problem using vision_opencv to get image from kinect?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have kinect which is working well and I can get image by running `openni.launch` and `rviz`.
I want to subscribe this kinect image in to a node and change it to **opencv image format** from **ros image format** for image processing.
for doing the same I am following the following page.
http://dasl.mem.drexel.edu/wiki/index.php/How_to_make_ROS_and_Opencv_work_together

however using `rosmake` it is showing following error .....

```
/opt/ros/groovy/share/vision_opencv/roscv/src/simplecanny.cpp:12:32: fatal error: cv_bridge/CvBridge.h: No such file or directory
  compilation terminated.
  make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/roscv.dir/src/simplecanny.cpp.o] Error 1
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/opt/ros/groovy/share/vision_opencv/roscv/build'
  make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/roscv.dir/all] Error 2
  make[2]: Leaving directory `/opt/ros/groovy/share/vision_opencv/roscv/build'
  make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
  make[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/ros/groovy/share/vision_opencv/roscv/build'
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package roscv written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/admin-pc/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20131207-114326/roscv/build_output.log
[rosmake-4] Finished <<< roscv [FAIL] [ 2.82 seconds ]                          
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package roscv. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[ rosmake ] Results:                                                            
[ rosmake ] Built 39 packages with 1 failures.                                  
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                         
[ rosmake ] /home/admin-pc/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20131207-114326
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/107596/having-problem-using-vision_opencv-to-get-image-from-kinect?/) by [lifelonglearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/5249/lifelonglearner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 205 on 2013-12-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `cv_bridge/CvBridge.h` is old and not used anymore. Use API given in

```
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>
```

instead...

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [enthurzan](https://answers.ros.org/users/31050/enthurzan/) on 2017-07-06**:
If i take out this #include statement:

```
#include <cv_bridge/CvBridge.h>
```

Then I lose the functionality of my code, yet I don't even have that package. How do I install CvBridge.h from the command line? I am gettting this error:

```
fatal error: cv_bridge/CvBridge.h: No such file or directory
```